# Remove factor columns in data frame which contain specific value

Tags: r, dataframe, subset, categorical-data

I have a data frame which contain categorical variables - factors with 2 levels or 1 level. I am trying to remove all columns which have only level. Since I have more than 300 categorical variables, I would like to use looping or function.

Here is a sample code with only 5 columns to make it simple here:

```
B1 <- as.factor(c(1,1,1,1,1,1))
B2 <- as.factor(c(1,0,1,1,0,0))
B3 <- as.factor(c(0,1,1,0,1,0))
B4 <- as.factor(c(0,0,0,0,0,0))
B5 <- as.factor(c(1,0,1,0,1,0))
df <- data.frame(B1,B2,B3,B4,B5)
```

In this case I would like to drop column B1 and B4 because they have only one level and have a data frame like this

```
   B2 B3 B5
1  1  0  1
2  0  1  0
3  1  1  1
4  1  0  0
5  0  1  1
6  0  0  0
```

I tried to use several codes but I dont get the desired result.

```
df1 <- data.frame(df1[,xqual[,c(1:5)] == "1" & df[ ,c(1:5)] == "0"])
```

or

```
for (i in 2:dim(df)[2]){
  df1[,i] = which(df[,i] == "1" & df[,i] == "0") 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another base R option:

```
df[sapply(df, nlevels) > 1]
  B2 B3 B5
1  1  0  1
2  0  1  0
3  1  1  1
4  1  0  0
5  0  1  1
6  0  0  0
```

Or using `Filter`:

```
Filter(\(x) nlevels(x) - 1, df)
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `select` to select columns having more than one unique value

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   select(where(~ n_distinct(.) > 1))
```

-ouptut

```
 B2 B3 B5
1  1  0  1
2  0  1  0
3  1  1  1
4  1  0  0
5  0  1  1
6  0  0  0
```

---

Or we can look for specific values by wrwapping with `all`

```
df %>%
    select(where(~ all(c(0, 1) %in% .)))
```

---

or with `Filter` in `base R`

```
Filter(\(x) length(unique(x)) > 1, df)
```

-outut

```
   B2 B3 B5
1  1  0  1
2  0  1  0
3  1  1  1
4  1  0  0
5  0  1  1
6  0  0  0
```

---

Or with `var`

```
Filter(var, type.convert(df, as.is = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another base R option

```
> Filter(function(v) var(as.integer(v)),df)
  B2 B3 B5
1  1  0  1
2  0  1  0
3  1  1  1
4  1  0  0
5  0  1  1
6  0  0  0
```